# Create an intent that launches into the current state of the application

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a navigation drawer that sits on top of all my activities. This drawer allows the user to switch from application to application quickly. I want the drawer to launch the application that is selected.  This portion is working correctly.

```
   private void selectItem(int position) {

        if (position != 0) {
          String packageName = ((DrawerItem) mDrawerItems.getItem(position)).getPackageName();
          Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
          .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
          startActivityIfNeeded(intent, 0);
          // close the drawer
          finish();
          }
    }
```

Most of the applications have two activities, activity A (the default launch) and activity B. I want the intent to launch the app in the state it was left in. Currently, every time the app is launched from the drawer, it will launch into the A activity. If the app was last in the B activity, I would like the app to return to B activity rather than A activity. 

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using SharedPreferences for storing your current session?

Comment: I have not yet.  I was hoping to find a way to do this from the intent.

Comment: By 'If the app was last in the B activity, I would like the app to return to B activity rather than A activity' the application is in what state. Is app closed or in currently on standby?